# ¿Cómo extraer múltiples valores con distintos patrones regulares de un vector de texto?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Tengo un `data.frame` dónde en una de las columna tengo información que me interesa extraer, básicamente en la forma `<clave> <valor>` pero con patrones variables y múltiples. Ejemplo:

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:3,
                 texto=c('"campo1=A" "campoX<B>"','"campo2=C" "campo3 : D"', '"campo1=E" "campo3 : F"')
)

df

  id                   texto
1  1  "campo1=A" "campoX<B>"
2  2 "campo2=C" "campo3 : D"
3  3 "campo1=E" "campo3 : F"
```

La idea es usar patrones regulares, por la flexibilidad que eventualmente se necesitaría, en la realidad los patrones de extracción son algo más complejos que este ejemplo. Finalmente quisiera terminar con un `data.frame` o `matrix` similar a esta:

```
  campo1 campo2 campox campo3
1      A   <NA>      B   <NA>
2   <NA>      C   <NA>      D
3      E   <NA>   <NA>      F
```

Cada fila corresponde a una fila del `data.frame` original, cada columna es una de las claves buscadas y obviamente se completan con el valor, siempre que este exista (eventualmente, podría haber filas con todas las columnas vacías), no se espera que exista más de una ocurrencia de cada clave en cada fila.

Intente usar el paquete `stringr`, por la función `str_match_all()` y se consigue algo interesante, pero no del todo cercano a lo que busco:

```
library(stringr)

str_match_all(string = c('"campo1=A"', '"campo2=C" "campo3 : D"'), 
              pattern = '"campo1=([^\\"]*)|"campo2=([^\\"]*)|"campo3 : ([^\\"]*)')
    
[[1]]
     [,1]         [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "\"campo1=A" "A"  NA   NA  

[[2]]
     [,1]           [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "\"campo2=C"   NA   "C"  NA  
[2,] "\"campo3 : D" NA   NA   "D"
```

Con el `or`  (`|`) podríamos encadenar todos los patrones que tenemos para cada valor a extraer, pero todavía habría que establecer que patrón encontrado corresponde a cada clave y transformar todo en un `data.frame`. ¿Hay algo como lo que busco usando `stringr`? ¿Hay otra forma de resolverlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que he podido hacer se basa totalmente e R base y tiene seguramente su penalidad en cuanto a performance, pero básicamente la solución encontrada pasa por:

- Definir un vector de claves y otro con los patrones de cada una de estas
- analizar cada patrón y agregar los grupos extraídos en una columna nueva del `data.frame` que queremos como resultado

Veamos:

```
str_extract_to_df <- function(column_string, patterns, newcolumns) {
  
  lst <- list()
  for(i in seq(patterns)) {
    v <- gsub(patterns[i], "\\1", regmatches(column_string,gregexpr(patterns[i],column_string)))
    v[v == "character(0)"] <- NA
    lst[[newcolumns[i]]] <- v
  }
  as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,lst))
}
```

Y ahora si:

```
patterns <- c('"campo1=([^\\"]*)', 
              '"campo2=([^\\"]*)', 
              '"campoX<([^>]*)',
              '"campo3 : ([^\\"]*)')
newcolumns <- c('campo1', 
                'campo2', 
                'campox', 
                'campo3')

str_extract_to_df(df$texto, patterns, newcolumns)
    
  campo1 campo2 campox campo3
1      A   <NA>      B   <NA>
2   <NA>      C   <NA>      D
3      E   <NA>   <NA>      F
```